# Can we have a uniform way for Parsha tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

Can we have a uniform way to create parsha tags, so that we don't end up with tags like [parshat-korach](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parshat-korach), [parshas-yisro](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/parshas-yisro), and [vayechi](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vayechi)?

Comment: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/1857/make-parsha-tags-consistent

Comment: @IsaacMoses So which should be closed as a dupe?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion: Make them all [parshat-xxxxx], and synonymize the [parshas-xxxxxx].

Comment: Why? Why not [purushath-xxxxx] as they were more likely originally pronounced?